# How do I update an Android app database data daily?

Tags: android, database, google-play

I'm developing an Android app I want to publish on Google Play that shows data from its internal database.

I'd like to insert new data in the app internal database once a day for the next n years, this operation should be done automatically from a program that scrapes the internet for new information.

So, when a user opens the app on his mobile, the app internal database has to be updated with the new data, if there is (without have to update the whole app).

Is there a solution?

**Without a database on a server**

Comment: update the database on start....or what exactly do You want to know? Show us what You got

Comment: yes, you can make a code to scrap the internet and parse results and insert it in the database, missing part for you is to store last update date in sharedPreferences so you won't do it twice/day

Comment: The program that scrapes the internet runs on my pc, not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I will outline my proposed architecture for your problem:

You should have a server with a database that will hold all your data and an api endpoint for the android client to get the updates. Something like

```
http://yourhost/get_updates?since=13435465345.
```

Then the server should use the 'since' param to query for data updates, something like

```
select * from news where updatedAt>:since
```

The server will generate a responce based on that query in your favorite format (json or xml) and return it to the client. The client will take the data and insert it in the local database, and store the current timestamp as an update point (to use is as future 'since' param)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a server?

Comment: It depends on the use case. Are you scraping just a page or two? Then yes. But if you want to look in a bunch of pages then a server is required

Comment: A database doesn't have to be sql, you could use files in the filesystem to store data.

Comment: a lot of pages...
I think I'll update the whole app every time my program finds new information.

Comment: but in this case if my database is 5mb every time I update the app does the user need to download the whole database or is there a way to download only the new data?

Comment: You should use the above trick with the 'since' timestamp to get only updates